# Marklogic How to convert xquery to cts javascript

Tags: marklogic

How can I translate this xquery code into javascript.  I'm familiar Xquery and learning to convert to Marklogic JavaScript.  Thanks.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace rec="http://mod.com/record";
declare namespace meta="http://mod.com/record/meta";

let $uris := cts:uris(
                      (),
                      (),
                     cts:and-query((
                        cts:collection-query("/document/pdf"),
                        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("rec:PdfExists"),"1")
                        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("meta:Access"),  ("2150951","2148831","2141426")
                        )
                   ))
             )
return $uris
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have not tested it, this is the syntactically correct equivalent:

```
cts.uris(
                      "",
                      [],
                     cts.andQuery([
                        cts.collectionQuery("/document/pdf"),
                        cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName("http://mod.com/record", "PdfExists"),"1"),
                        cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName("http://mod.com/record/meta", "Access"),  ["2150951","2148831","2141426"])
                   ])
             )
```

Comment: oh I see in xquery I have to declare namespace. But in javascript you put namespace in fn.QName.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @thichxai You could also declare the namespaces as variables and then pass it in as the first parameter of fn.QName if you would like to.